# scroll snap vertical with free scroll horizontal

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js

I've been trying to put together a portfolio style site that scroll/snaps vertically for the different galleries and then scrolls freely (no snap) horizontally to view the galleries content (imgs floated right).

I've been trying to build it off one of the few frameworks (nice features and responsive) out there but they all end up breaking when i set a large width (ex: 80000px).

Fullpage.js has a feature with [free vertical scrolling](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage) before the snap which makes me think it would be possible to do this horizontally. 
Another interesting example is [query.panelsnap](http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/) which has internal scrolling frames but with both of these(and others i've tried) I wasn't able to set a large horizontal width without breaking the plugins snap feature.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this horizontal scrolling to work alongside the vertical snapping? I've been having no success!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you need an horizontal scrolling? Can't you just use an slider for that? It is not common in websites to have horizontal scrolls.

Comment: If somebody needs there's a plugin doing exactly this: http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Try MouseSwipe at:

http://torontographic.wordpress.com/

It might be what you need no sure.